# Splitting a set of object into several subsets according to certain evaluation

Tags: algorithm, heuristics, fuzzy

Suppose I have a set of objects, `S`.  There is an algorithm `f` that, given a set `S` builds certain data structure `D` on it: `f(S) = D`.  If `S` is large and/or contains vastly different objects, `D` becomes large, to the point of being unusable (i.e. not fitting in allotted memory).  To overcome this, I split `S` into several non-intersecting subsets: `S = S1 + S2 + ... + Sn` and build `Di` for each subset.  Using `n` structures is less efficient than using one, but at least this way I can fit into memory constraints.  Since size of `f(S)` grows faster than `S` itself, combined size of `Di` is much less than size of `D`.

However, it is still desirable to reduce `n`, i.e. the number of subsets; or reduce the combined size of `Di`.  For this, I need to split `S` in such a way that each `Si` contains "similar" objects, because then `f` will produce a smaller output structure if input objects are "similar enough" to each other.

The problems is that while "similarity" of objects in `S` and size of `f(S)` do correlate, there is no way to compute the latter other than just evaluating `f(S)`, and `f` is not quite fast.

Algorithm I have currently is to iteratively add each next object from `S` into one of `Si`, so that this results in the least possible (at this stage) increase in combined `Di` size:

```
for x in S:
    i = such i that
             size(f(Si + {x})) - size(f(Si))
             is min
    Si = Si + {x}
```

This gives practically useful results, but certainly pretty far from optimum (i.e. the minimal possible combined size).  Also, this is *slow*.  To speed up somewhat, I compute `size(f(Si + {x})) - size(f(Si))` only for those `i` where `x` is "similar enough" to objects already in `Si`.

Is there any standard approach to such kinds of problems?

I know of branch and bounds algorithm family, but it cannot be applied here because it would be prohibitively slow.  My guess is that it is simply not possible to compute optimal distribution of `S` into `Si` in reasonable time.  But is there some common iteratively improving algorithm?

**EDIT:**

As comments noted, I never defined "similarity".  In fact, all I want is to split in such subsets `Si` that combined size of `Di = f(Si)` is minimal or at least small enough.  "Similarity" is defined only as this and unfortunately simply cannot be computed easily.  I do have a simple approximation, but it is only that — an approximation.

So, what I need is a (likely heuristical) algorithm that minimizes `sum f(Si)` given that there is *no* simple way to compute the latter — only approximations I use to throw away cases that are very unlikely to give good results.

Comment: How do you define "similar"? Maybe you can formulate it in a way to be able to use an apriori algorithm.

Comment: Since the size delta is completely dependent on `f(S)`, and is correlated with "similarity"... I'm not sure what kind of algorithm you'd expect to find, or how it could help, other than defining "similarity" specifically for size impact on `f(S)` (as @honk) said, and then it becomes trivial to partition.

Comment: @honk: Well, "similarity" is some intrinsic property of objects or, rather, a set of them.  In my case the objects themselves can be seen as maps of points to values; similar objects have many common points, even better if they have the same values at the same points.  Unfortunately, this is related but *not* directly defining the size of `f` output.

Comment: @honk: Also, see the edit in the question itself.

Comment: @doublep: If "similarity" is only defined by the size of the sets it introduces (like suggested in your edit), make it produce `size(S)/size(available_memory)` distinct sets. But probably that's not what you meant.

Comment: @honk: Size of `f(Si)`, not just the sets.

Answer (score 0):

About the slowness I found that in similar problems a good-enough solution is to compute the match just by picking a fixed number of random candidates.

True that the result will not be the best one (often worse than the full "greedy" solution you implemented) but it in my experience not too bad and you can decide the speed... it can even be implemented in a prescribed amount of time (that is you keep searching until the allocated time expires).

Another option I use is to keep searching until I see no improvement for a while.

To get past the greedy logic you could keep a queue of N "x" elements and trying to pack them simultaneously in groups of "k" (with k < N).
In this case I found that is important to also keep the "age" of an element in the queue and to use it as a "prize" for the result to avoid keeping "bad" elements forever in the queue because others will always match better (this would make the queue search useless and the results would be basically the same as the greedy approach).

Comment: I'm not sure anything will work, but there are certainly some good ideas here worth trying.

Comment: Also to note, my solution is not "full".  It selects best possible candidate at each given iteration, yes, but that is not the same as best partioning overall.

Comment: Choosing the single most promising move is what is conventionally called the "greedy" approach... I called your solution full-greedy because you said you are trying all moves. When there are many such possible moves I simply found that in several problems a quasi-greedy that only checks a random subset of the possible moves is not much worse as value but can be a lot faster.

Comment: Ah, I see.  However, I don't try all possible moves.  As noted in the question, I only try those "where `x` is "similar enough" to objects already in `Si`".  I.e. I discard cases that are very unlikely to give any good resutls according to heuristic.